# autotag-vim plugin doesn't index tags upon save

Tags: vim

I have installed the latest version of the autotag-vim plugin. The tags compiled statically works in my project. When ever I make changes to a file and save the `tags` file is not updated.

I have file called home_controller.rb as shown below

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    foo  # CTRL+] jumps to implementation
  end

private

  def foo
  end
end
```

If I modify the file to add new function and save the tag navigation doesn't work for the new function.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    foo
    bar  # CTRL+] does not jump to implementation after save
  end

private

  def foo
  end

  def bar
  end

end
```

I enabled the debug buffer by calling `:call AutoTagDebug()` and I noticed that tagging was happening as expected. But the `tags` file is not getting updated.

```
source = "C:\Users\user1\My Projects\test1\app\controllers\home_controller.rb"
drive = "C:", file = "\Users\user1\My Projects\test1\app\controllers"
tagsFile "C:\Users\user1\My Projects\test1\app\controllers\tags"
drive = "C:", file = "\Users\user1\My Projects\test1\app"
tagsFile "C:\Users\user1\My Projects\test1\app\tags"
drive = "C:", file = "\Users\user1\My Projects\test1"
tagsFile "C:\Users\user1\My Projects\test1\tags"
Stripping tags for test1/app/controllers/home_controller.rb from tags file C:\Users\user1\My Projects\test1\tags
```

Comment: You have a problem with a specific Vim plugin. You'll have more chances to get it fixed if you submit a bug to the author.

Comment: I have submitted this issue in the github prior to posting here.

Comment: You might want to take a look at another plugin that provides painless automatic tag generation: Indexer. I'm author of this plugin, thus if you have problems using it, I'm ready to help. Please refer to my another answer for details: http://goo.gl/T0QbC